# Area reverse geocoding

Tags: openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding

Is it possible to get the name of an area providing just the bounding box?

I'm not interested in specific points, what I'm trying to figure out is to get the name of the maximum polygon (I'm thinking in OSM here) within the bounding box I already have.

Clarifying example: Send bounding box containing part of New York and get "Brooklyn" as a response.

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516589/area-reverse-geocoding

Comment: @scai Already fixed